# How to add padding in a cell of a TGridPanel in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, layout, padding, margins, tgridpanel

I created a Delphi 10.4 VCL testing program. On the form, I created a one-row-multi-column TGridPanel and placed a TSpeedButton on column 0. The properties of column 0 are:

```
SizeStyle: ssAuto
Value: 50
```

Some properties of the TSpeedButton are:

```
Align: alClient
Anchors: all false
Margins: all 20
Width: 105
Height: 71
```

As you can see, I've added margin 20 for all 4 directions for the button. But I can't see the margin in the result.

[image]

How can I add some space between the button and the grid cell? You can download the project source at https://www.mediafire.com/file/x65ankhk17c7xk0/test1.rar/file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the VCL to respect your [`Margins`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Margins), you need to set [`AlignWithMargins`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.AlignWithMargins) to `True`.

You could have realised this yourself if you had read the documentation on `Margins`:

> **Note:** The `Margins` you set for the control have effect only when `AlignWithMargins` is set to `true` and `Align` is not set to `alNone`.